# Why is the below error not being caught in the catch block

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, axios

```
peopleService.create(personObject).then((returnedPerson) => {
  setPersons(persons.concat(returnedPerson));
  setMessage(`Added ${personObject.name}`);
  setNewName(" ");
  setPhone(" ");
  setTimeout(() => {
    setMessage(null);
  }, 3000);
}).catch(error =>{
 console.log(`${error.response.data.error}`)      
})
```

Full code repo is [HERE](https://github.com/shraja7/fullStackOpen/tree/main/part1/phonebook). Here is the error thrown when I enter a person whose name is shorter than 3 letters: [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhqZm.png)

Comment: Where does the error throw?

Comment: the only place it should be throwing is the front end app.js file, the error message doesn't show where exactly it's being thrown from or i'm just unaware of how to look